# What pattern/name should I use?

Tags: actionscript-3, design-patterns, naming-conventions, singleton

I have created a Singleton class that handles my project texts. What is the appropriate name of a Singleton class like this?

- TextManager?
- TextHandler?
- TextController?

Is there a difference in meaning of these names?

UPDATE:
The class stores the project text as xml and have a method for returning the correct text.

```
function getText(uid : String) : String
```

Comment: I would like to know why I should use Handler before other names.

Comment: TextController will be more in the MVC Space , Handler would indicated there are events

Comment: what specifically does the handler do?

Comment: It is basically a class that stores the project texts in xml format. But it also has some methods like getText(uid : String) : String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually sounds like a service or repository to me...

TextService or TextRepository?  TextModel?

But let me back up a bit... the Singleton pattern is a pretty bad way of accessing something like this.  Just google "Singleton pattern problems" if you want to see what I am talking about.  Plus, in AS3, you don't have private constructors so you can't implement the Singleton pattern in a pure way.

Instead, I really prefer composition via "Inversion of Control" (IoC) containers.  There are plenty of them out there for ActionScript.  They can be really lightweight but they decouple your components in a really elegant way.

Sorry to inject my thoughts here... ymmv :)

**EDIT -- More on eliminating Singleton pattern**

I have written about several [strategies on eliminating singletons](http://www.houseofbilz.com/archives/2009/05/02/what-to-do-about-those-pesky-singletons/) in your code.  This article was written for C#, but all the same principles apply.  In that article, I DON't talk explicitly about IoC containers.

Here is a pretty good article about [IoC in Flex](http://blogs.adobe.com/tomsugden/2009/07/the_trend_towards_inversionofc.html).  In addition, several frameworks give you IoC capabilities:

- [Swiz](http://swizframework.org/)
- [Robot Legs](http://www.robotlegs.org/)
- [fling](http://fling.riaforge.org/)
- [Cairngorm](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/Cairngorm)
- [flex-ioc](http://code.google.com/p/flex-ioc/)

Comment: Thanks. I have been thinking of TextModel. I would really like to see an example without Singleton implementation but with as easy access from multiple classes.

Comment: I think you need to look further into the concepts of Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control.  They exist specifically to do what you are asking.  They allow you to compose your objects without explicitly coupling them like the Singleton pattern does.  I edited my post to give some links to ways to eliminate the Singleton pattern, but still let multiple classes access your data.  Good luck :)

Answer (score 5):

I suppose it doesn't deal with adding/removing/... (-> managing) the texts (maybe just loading), so it isn't a "real" ***Manager***.

It also doesn't "***control***" the texts (something "You're only accessible from ...", "Return another value for that key if ...").

The class ***provides*** you with texts.

I suppose it's some Kind of ***localized text provider***, right?

So why don't you call it **`LocalizedTextProvider`**?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The class is not project specific. It does not load anything. It stores the project texts for easy access.

Answer (score 4):

I usually call something like this

`TextUtility`

or

`TextHelper`

the problem with 'handler' is that it implies some sort of event handling.  Same thing with 'Controller', it has meaning in a different context.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Controller is 'reserved' for the MVC model but I may be wrong.  TextHandler and TextManager may be better but at least at the place I work, 'Manager' in a service/class is generally discouraged since it is assumed that every class 'manages' something (this may just be culture-specific, though).

I'd vote for TextHandler out of those three.  It may also depend slightly on your programming language.

Comment: Programming language: Actionscript 3

Comment: Yeah, I believe it's still fine.

Answer (score 1):

All three of the names you proposed can all be interpreted in the same way. Some people prefer handlers while others might say controllers... it really is a matter of semantics. Whatever convention you choose to adopt just be consistent. The common notion that you should capture though is that the class which you are describing is not doing anything. It should only be in charge of delegating, since that's what managers do to employees and controllers do in the classic MVC paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

As I usually have Handler in the event/message handling context. Controller for actions and MVC stuff, I would go with something different:

- TextResources.get(key)
- I18n.get(key) (if your class is in fact used for internationalisation)

I usually reserve Helpers for classes allowing to simply transform some data into something to be used in the view.

Answer (score 0):

TextCache? Sounds like you are just using it to store and retrieve data...

Answer (score 0):

Why not :  `ProjectNameTexts`

```
FooTexts.getInstance().getText('hello_world');
```